# Base64 string ObjectToJsonObject has added \ before /

Tags: json, delphi

I am working in Delphi 10 Sydney.

I have to send a base64 string to an API in JSON format. I have shortened the base64 string for security reasons.

`FSignatureData` is the base64 string I want to send:

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/..`

But what I sent to the API is:

`\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/..`

I have an object:

```pascal
  TJSONSignature = class
   private
    FSignatureData: string;
  published
    property SignatureData: string read FSignatureData write FSignatureData;
```

I add this object as JSON to a JsonArray:

```pascal
var
  myJSONValue: TJSONObject;
begin
  myJSONValue := TJSON.ObjectToJsonObject(aSignature,[joIgnoreEmptyArrays,joIgnoreEmptyStrings]);
  if not assigned(FSignatures) then
    FSignatures := TJSONArray.Create;

  FSignatures.Add(myJSONValue);
```

This is the JSON I am sending:

```json
[
    {
        "signatureData": "\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/.."
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get the string in the JSON object without the `\`?

I tried to add the `SignatureData` as a pair, but then the value has also `\/` in it.

Comment: As i see from your question - you get exactly same string as you send and same as you want to send. So whats a problem?

Comment: apparently if you type \ / whitout a space is shows as /. I added some spaces so now you can see my problem

Comment: `\/` is a valid escape sequence in a JSON string which results in a `/` at the other end after proper processing. So unless the other end has broken JSON parsing there should be no issue.

Comment: @Brian it may be valid, but it's also redundant. `/` doesn't require escaping in JSON, only `"`, ```\```, and the ASCII control characters x00..x1F require escaping.

Comment: It maybe valid but I want to know how I can prevent ObjectToJsonObject to add \ so that the Base64 string is send correctly